# Android Button attributes

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a button in my xml layout thats causing a crash. I've been able to prevent the crash by either adding **android:bufferType="spannable"** to the layout file or removing the line **android:imeOptions="actionDone"**. I'm happy I was able to figure it out but I'm not understanding why either of those work as solutions. Can someone help explain? I have included below the initial stack trace, the code from the xml layout, the java code for my custom button class, and the line of code causing the error according to the stack trace. But like I mentioned before, I can fix the crash by either adding a specific line of code or remove a specific line. Thanks for the help in advance.

#### STACK TRACE

```
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1432)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at com.myapp.android.menu.LoginFragment.checkIfAnyFieldIsEmpty(LoginFragment.java:512)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at com.myapp.android.menu.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:183)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-02 09:18:19.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20587):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the snippets of code surrounding the error.

#### XML LAYOUT CODE

```
<com.myapp.android.view.StyledButton
        android:id="@+id/login_sign_in"
        style="@style/button_blue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/state_list_login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in" />
```

#### CUSTOM BUTTON JAVA CODE

```java
    public class StyledButton extends Button {
    //variables
    private final String BOLD = "fonts/arial.ttf";
    private final String NORMAL = "fonts/arial_bold.ttf";

    private String mCustomFont = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public StyledButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public StyledButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomAttributes(attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Set custom attributes
     * @param attrs
     */
    private void setCustomAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a=getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.StyledTextView);
        mCustomFont = a.getString(R.styleable.StyledTextView_fontAsset);
        if(mCustomFont != null) {
            if(!isInEditMode()) {
                CustomFontManager fontManager = CustomFontManager.getInstance();
                super.setTypeface(fontManager.getFont(getContext().getAssets(), mCustomFont));
            }
        }
        a.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Set type face
     */
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        CustomFontManager fontManager = CustomFontManager.getInstance();
        if(isInEditMode()) {
            super.setTypeface(tf,style);
            return;
        }
        if(mCustomFont!=null) {
            super.setTypeface(fontManager.getFont(getContext().getAssets(), mCustomFont));
            return;
        }
        switch (style) {
            case Typeface.NORMAL:
                super.setTypeface(fontManager.getFont(getContext().getAssets(), NORMAL));
                break;
            case Typeface.BOLD:
                super.setTypeface(fontManager.getFont(getContext().getAssets(), BOLD));
                break;
            default:
                super.setTypeface(fontManager.getFont(getContext().getAssets(), NORMAL));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### JAVA CODE CAUSING ERROR

```java
    private StyledButton mSignIn;

    public void checkIfAnyFieldIsEmpty() {
    if (mEmailEmpty || mPasswordEmpty) {
        mSignIn.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mSignIn.setEnabled(true);
    } 
}
```